# (-212:Parsing error) in Object Detection using yolo, google colab and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

I was trying object detection for the first time and got this error. I read various posts and saw many videos but couldn't find any solution to it. Can some please help me to solve this error.

- I have only installed open cv using pip command.
- All the training and testing was done on google colab.
- I downloaded the yolov3_training_last.weights yolov3_testing.cfg from
  drive and pasted in the same folder in which code was present.
- I ran the code on atom and installed script as its package.

**Error -**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\test\New folder\Object_Detection.py", line 5, in 
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: yolov3_testing.cfg in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::readNetFromDar

**Code -**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#net = cv2.dnn.readNet('D:\\test\\New folder\\yolov3_training_last.weights', 'D:\\test\\New folder\\yolov3_testing.cfg')
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')

classes = []
#with open("D:\\test\\New folder\\classes.txt", "r") as f:
with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\test\\New folder\\test1.mp4')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test1.mp4')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your cfg file for yolov3 which is making it unable to parse through it to collect the viable information.

Try running the code again and saving the model appropriately. Run the saved weights again in colab and check if it works. If it works there it should in atom too. Also, are you sure these are the right parameters for the function cv2.dnn.readNet() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
net=cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov3_custom.cfg",r"Downloads\yolov3_custom_6000.weights")
```

and make sure darknet is installed in your local system.