# error cv2.error: OpenCV (error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

My model code is given below. I am beginner in python and have a college project to calculate social distancing.

I am getting the error:

```
C:\Users\nikki\pypro>python3 social-distance-yolo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikki\pypro\social-distance-yolo.py", line 38, in <module>
    net, output_layers, classes = load_model.loading_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\nikki\pypro\setup\load_model.py", line 12, in loading_dependencies
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weightsPath, cfgPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: C:\Users\nikki\pypro\pypro/utils/model/yolov4.cfg in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::readNetFromDarknet'
```

My Model Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 

foldersPath = "utils/model/"
weightsPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), foldersPath, "yolov4.weights")
cfgPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), foldersPath, "yolov4.cfg")
coco_namePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "utils/", "coco.names")

def loading_dependencies():

    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weightsPath, cfgPath)

    classes = []

    with open(coco_namePath, "r") as f:
        classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)
    
    return net, output_layers, classes
```

Can Anyone Please help me I have tried lots option like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627050/212parsing-error-in-object-detection-using-yolo-google-colab-and-opencv):

Comment: the file cannot be parsed. are you sure the correct path is `C:\Users\nikki\pypro\pypro/utils/model/yolov4.cfg` ? (notice there are 2 pypro folders)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in backslashes/forward slashes

```
C:\Users\nikki\pypro\pypro/utils/model/yolov4.cfg
```

Try to check this and it should work

And in your code if you use CPU  backend following line:

```
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

should be replaced with:

```
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

Because your code is for CUDA backend (OpenCV compiled with CUDA flags) and operates with 2d data tensor